# Using C++ classes in objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, class

I have an application written in C++. I've read some articles on how we can use C++ classes in objective-c. My question is will it work if I use my application, which is designed for windows, for iPhone? What I mean to say is can I use the classes used in this application for an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to use classes that don't rely on platform-dependent libraries.